# Calculating core length and question regarding B-H curve

Tags: circuit-analysis, magnetics, hysteresis

[image]

[image]

I understand the problem and all (or so I thought), but my answer was way off. Looking at the solution, I realized that I calculated the core length wrong.

I don't understand how though. Shouldn't \$l_c= 2 \pi(r_o+r_i)/2 -g\$? In the solution, they gave  \$l_c= 2\pi(r_o-r_i) -g\$ How does this make sense? What am I missing?

Also, if I want to find \$\mu\$ from B-H curve, do I take B/H or dB/dH?

Comment: What book is this? Link to it please...

Answer (score 1):

> I realized that I calculated the core length wrong.

The mid point radius of the core is the average of \$R_0\$ and \$R_1\$: -

$$\dfrac{R_0 + R_1}{2}$$

Therefore the ungapped circumference is: -

$$2\pi\cdot\dfrac{R_0 + R_1}{2}$$

> In the solution, they gave \$l_c=2π(r_o−r_i)\$

That is incorrect.

> Also, if I want to find μ from B-H curve, do I take B/H or dB/dH?

$$\mu\cdot H = B$$

But only in the linear(ish) portion of the curve. My recommendation is to look at the graph and estimate the H-field.

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't \$l_c=2π(R_o+R_i)/2−g\$?

For toroidal cores, the well-known formula of mean MPL is:
$$
\mathrm{\ell_c=\frac{2\pi\ (R_o-R_i)}{ln(R_o/R_i)}-\ell_g}
$$

Both formulas give the same result. So yes, you should be correct. If not then I should have missed something.

> Also, if I want to find μ from the B-H curve, do I take \$B/H\$ or \$dB/dH\$?

\$\mu\$ is the slope of the B-H curve at a \$\mathrm{(B, H)}\$ point. If the curve is linear then you can obtain it from \$\mu=B/H\$.